# How to eliminate the "\t" when fetching text with space at the end ,inside h1 tag using xpath in python?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch this text "Aggreko (AGGK) "(check the Image) from a web page. when using xpath to fetch it, i am getting the below mentioned output.

Code:

```
companyName = root.xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/text()')
```

output:

```
['3I Group PLC (III)\t']
```

Assuming it's because of white space at the end, tried to rewrite the code as below. Yet got the same output.

Code :

```
companyName = root.xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/text()[normalize-space()]')
```

[image]

how do i eliminate this \t ?

Comment: Can you post a complete xml example as text? It doesn't have to be large, just enough that we can copy/paste and have something to test with. Also, mention which xpath processor you are using.

Comment: I think its `'normalize-space(//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/text())'` but my xpath is kind of rusty.

Comment: @tdelaney 'normalize-space(//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/text())' has worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Python `strip()` method.

```
companyName = root.xpath('//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/text()').strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap your query like this:

```
normalize-space(//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1)
```

Or try

```
//*[@id="leftColumn"]/div[1]/h1/[normalize-space(text())]
```